# R function `poly` in logistic regression not giving orthogonal results

Tags: r, logistic, nonlinear-regression, polynomial

After reviewing [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19484582/11751750), I have been interested in using the polynomial function within logistic regression. As I understand it, the `poly` function is useful because it produces orthogonal polynomials that have the ability to assess the contribution of each additional polynomial term. However, I am getting results that vary drastically when adding subsequent terms in logistic regression for predicting categorical variables.

I am attaching a brief example using the same data as the previous comment, but trying to predict a categorical outcome that is TRUE if mpg > mean(mpg) and FALSE if mpg < mean(mpg)

```
library(ISLR)

fm2 <-  glm(mpg > mean(mpg) ~poly(horsepower,1), family = "binomial", data=Auto)
cbind(coef(fm2))
#                           [,1]
# (Intercept)          -1.015118
# poly(horsepower, 1) -72.853345

fm3 <- glm(mpg > mean(mpg) ~poly(horsepower,2), family = "binomial", data=Auto)
cbind(coef(fm3))
#                             [,1]
# (Intercept)           -0.5624529
# poly(horsepower, 2)1 -57.7684809
# poly(horsepower, 2)2  12.3423471
```

Furthermore, it seems that not using the `poly` function at all has different results from using the `poly` function:

```
library(tidyverse)

fm2 <-  glm(mpg > mean(mpg) ~poly(horsepower,1), family = "binomial", data=Auto)
cbind(coef(fm2))
#                           [,1]
# (Intercept)          -1.015118
# poly(horsepower, 1) -72.853345

fm2_alt <-  glm(mpg > mean(mpg) ~horsepower, family = "binomial", data=Auto)
cbind(coef(fm2_alt))
#                    [,1]
# (Intercept)  8.98463249
# horsepower  -0.09571943
```

In an attempt to visualize what is going on, I have plotted both of these logistic regression functions overlying two different distributions:

- The original distribution
- The original distribution translated to have a mean of zero.

```
func_fm2 <- function(x) 1/(1+exp(-(coef(fm2)[1] + (coef(fm2)[2] * x))))
func_fm2_alt <- function(x) 1/(1+exp(-(coef(fm2_alt)[1] + (coef(fm2_alt)[2] * x))))

ggplot(Auto) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(x = horsepower,y = as.numeric(mpg>mean(mpg))), color = "darkblue") + 
  geom_jitter(aes(x = horsepower - mean(horsepower),y = as.numeric(mpg>mean(mpg))), color = "darkred") + 
  stat_function(fun=func_fm2, colour="orange") + 
  stat_function(fun=func_fm2_alt, colour="cyan") + 
  xlim(c(-50,200)) + 
  labs(title = "Logistic Regression of horsepower and mpg",
       subtitle = "Original distribution in dark blue. Shifted distribution in dark red.",
       caption = " Logistic Regression fit plotted. `poly` fit in orange. non-`poly` fit in cyan.")
```

[image]

Am I doing something completely wrong? Should I be using a different function for polynomial logistic regression? Or rather, is it valid to first translate the distribution to have a mean of zero, and then subsequently add polynomial terms by the `poly` function?

Comment: +1.  For some insight, redo your initial regressions using `lm` rather than `glm` and compare the estimated coefficients.